# Delete a Registry key using C#

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I am trying to delete a Registry key like this:

```
RegistryKey oRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts", true);

oRegistryKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(".");
```

But that is giving me an exception:

> Cannot delete a subkey tree because the subkey does not exist

If I change `DeleteSubKeyTree` to `DeleteSubKey`, I receive a different exception:

> Registry key has subkeys and recursive removes are not supported by this method

Comment: Pretty logical errors I think, search them up in regedit.exe, verify the tree and adjust your code.

Comment: I've verified this thing its there in the regedit at the same place. not getting what to do now

Comment: So you want to open Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer and DeleteSubKeyTree("FileExts").  Easy peasy.  Careful with that chainsaw.

Comment: The `o` prefix in your variable `oRegistryKey` represents what is known as [Systems Hungarian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/768316/1497596) notation. Microsoft discourages this variable naming practice when writing code for the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string str = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts";
string[] strSplit = strLocal.Split('\\');
            using (RegistryKey oRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts", true))
            {
                RegistryKey hdr = oRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(strSplit[strSplit.Length-2], true);
                foreach (String key in hdr.GetSubKeyNames())
                    hdr.DeleteSubKey(key);
                hdr.Close();
                oRegistryKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(strSplit[strSplit.Length - 2]);
            }
```

Also check: [Registry in .NET: DeleteSubKeyTree says the subkey does not exists, but hey, it does!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959419/registry-in-net-deletesubkeytree-says-the-subkey-does-not-exists-but-hey-it)

Comment: exception : No value exists with that name

Comment: thanks for help @Rahul Tripathi the link has worked fine.

Comment: This is unnecessary, both DeleteSubKey and DeleteSubKeyTree work with empty string. Key should have write access.

Answer (score 4):

The approach outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250387/1497596) is needlessly complex because [DeleteSubKeyTree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3yfwzfx(v=vs.110).aspx) is recursive. From its documentation on MSDN:

> Deletes a subkey and any child subkeys recursively.

So, if your goal is to delete the user's `FileExts` key, do this:

```cs
string explorerKeyPath = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer";

using (RegistryKey explorerKey =
    Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(explorerKeyPath, writable: true))
{
    if (explorerKey != null)
    {
        explorerKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("FileExts");
    }
}
```

However, are you sure that you *really* want to delete a user's `FileExts` key? I believe that most would consider doing so would be unreasonably destructive and reckless. A more common scenario would be deleting a *single file extension key* (e.g., [`.hdr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2959419/1497596)) from the `FileExts` key.

Finally, note that `DeleteSubKeyTree` is overloaded. Here is the signature of the [second version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411622(v=vs.110).aspx) of this method:

```cs
public void DeleteSubKeyTree(
    string subkey,
    bool throwOnMissingSubKey
)
```

With this version, if `subkey` does not exist and `throwOnMissingSubKey` is false, `DeleteSubKeyTree` will simply return without making any changes to the Registry.

Comment: This does not work on Windows 10. The key is definately there...

Answer (score 2):

Please pay attention to 32 or 64 registry.
NOTE: `RegistryView.Registry64` it's the key of the problem.

This is my implementation that works for me:

```
public static void DeleteRegistryFolder(RegistryHive registryHive, string fullPathKeyToDelete)
{
    using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(registryHive, RegistryView.Registry64))
    {
        baseKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(fullPathKeyToDelete);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var baseKeyString = $@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyApp";

DeleteRegistryFolder(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, baseKeyString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you ............

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/166232/C-delete-a-registry-key-cannot-get-it-done

Answer (score 0):

Both methods `DeleteSubKey` and `DeleteSubKeyTree` are deleting the current key if the 'subkey' parameter is empty string, like `key.DeleteSubKey("");`

Key should have write access.
It has to be closed/disposed regular way.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to check the registry key:

```
using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts"))
    if (Key != null)
    {    
       key.DeleteValue("."); //delete if exist
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("key not found");
    }
```

Comment: Additional information: No value exists with that name