# Deleting registrry subkey doesnt delete,no error was throwed

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to delete some registry key via C#, but to code doesn't effect about the registry, I opened Visual Studio as administrator, I am trying to delete a key located in this path:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects`

[image]

Here my code:

```
string RegBHO = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";
string guid = "{b908e54f-8c58-4d5d-8762-60d7d675cd39}";
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegBHO, true);
registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
```

But the folder named `{b908e54f-8c58-4d5d-8762-60d7d675cd39}` still exist enen after I run the code (I clicked F5 to refresh registry list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a Registry key using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250244/delete-a-registry-key-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you manually create the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects\{b908e54f-8c58-4d5d-8762-60d7d675cd39}` and run your program to see if it's deleted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you are trying to delete a *32bit* key from a *64bit* application or vice-versa.

You will need to use the appropriate bitness in your app, or use the following to *read* / *write* / *Delete* the *keys*

[RegistryView Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=netframework-4.8)

> Specifies which registry view to target on a 64-bit operating system.

with

[RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey?view=netframework-4.8)

> Opens a new RegistryKey that represents the requested key on the local
>   machine with the specified view.
>
> **RegistryView Enumeration** : On the 64-bit version of Windows, portions of the registry are stored
>   separately for 32-bit and 64-bit applications. There is a 32-bit view
>   for 32-bit applications and a 64-bit view for 64-bit applications.
>
> You can specify a registry view when you use the `OpenBaseKey` and
>   `OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive, String, RegistryView)` methods, and the
>   FromHandle property on a RegistryKey object.

**Example**

```
using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{

}
```