# Unable to delete subkey tree in c#

Tags: c#, registry

Whenever I run the code below it throws an exception that the subkey does not exist though it actually exists. Am I doing something incorrectly? The purpose is to delete subkeys under a registry key recursively. My visual studio is running on x64:

```
string registryKey = @"Software\Google\Chrome";
RegistryKey hkcuChrome = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(registryKey, writable: true);
        string[] hkcu_subkeys = hkcuChrome.GetSubKeyNames();
        if (hkcuChrome != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < hkcu_subkeys.Length; i++)
            {
                hkcuChrome.DeleteSubKeyTree(hkcu_subkeys[i]);

            }
        }

        hkcuChrome.Close();
```

Comment: What's `String.Format` supposed to be accomplishing here? Your input is almost certainly not a format string.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert sorry, error with copy pasting, I've modified the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959419/registry-in-net-deletesubkeytree-says-the-subkey-does-not-exists-but-hey-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registry in .NET: DeleteSubKeyTree says the subkey does not exists, but hey, it does!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959419/registry-in-net-deletesubkeytree-says-the-subkey-does-not-exists-but-hey-it)

Comment: No unfortunately

Comment: I've been searching all over stackoverflow and none even answered my question.